# Combine tables and sql from 2 reports without the use of subreports

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, crystal-reports, report

Is there a way that I can take two reports, each with seperate SQL and Queries, and combine them onto a single report without tampering with their sql or queries?

I am currently trying to 'make a report' by using information from 2 all ready established and made reports. The two reports are an **InventoryAllocationWorkOrder** report and an **InventoryAllocationSalesOrder** report. I've started by simply making a copy and editing the WorkOrder report (which ive done and actually looks nice) but now im at teh part where i need the information from the other report (SalesOrder).

I am new to SQL and iReport but I dont believe what I am trying to do is as hard as im making it. I do know about subreports but I am simply asking if there is another way to combine the two on one report without a master report.

Thank you for helping me learn!

I did attempt to add photos to this post but am unable to without 10 reputation. I will do my best to answer questions though!

Comment: Fast Solution...See the Sub Report feature of SSRS. Better solution, create a new report and re-work your queries.  Depending on the complexity of the reports.

Answer (score 0):

Fast Solution...See the Sub Report feature of Crystal, Active Reports or SSRS.

They all have a "sub report" type features that let you embed an existing report into a "Parent" report.

[Crystal SubReports](http://www.teachucomp.com/subreports-in-crystal-reports-2013-tutorial/)

Better solution, create a new report and re-work your queries.  Depending on the complexity of the reports.

Comment: I think that is my issue then. I want to start from scratch but because the reports were made from someone else currently I am having a very difficult time understanding them.

Comment: If the question is tagged correctly, OP is using Crystal Reports, and not SSRS.